# How to convert double type to float in this NeRF code?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

```
class NeRF(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, D=8, W=256, input_ch=60, input_ch_views=24, output_ch=4, skip=4, use_view_dirs=True):
        ...

    def forward(self, input_pts, input_views=None):
        h = input_pts.clone()
        for i, _ in enumerate(self.pts_linears):
            h = F.relu(self.pts_linears[i](h))
            if i == self.skip:
                h = torch.cat([input_pts, h], -1)

        ...
```

Error part:

```
---> 40             h = F.relu(self.pts_linears[i](h))
...
RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Double
```

How do I convert it to a float variable? And I would like to ask for an explanation of why the source code does not report an error.

Answer (score 0):

first convert input to float tensor

```
h=input_pts.clone().float()
```